# Error on creating UpgradeSchema.php

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, upgradeschema, database-schema

```
<?php
    namespace Essence\Slider\Setup;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

    class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface {
        public function upgrade(
            SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
            ModuleContextInterface $context
        ){

            $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();
            if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0', '<')){
                if(!$installer->tableExists('bt_essence_slider')) {
                    $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                        $installer->getTable('bt_essence_slider')
                    )
                    ->addColumn(
                        'id',
                        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                        null,
                        [
                            'identity' => true,
                            'nullable' => false,
                            'primary'  => true,
                            'unsigned' => true 
                        ],
                        'Banner ID'
                    )
                    ->addColumn(
                        'banner_name',
                        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        255,
                        [
                            'nullable' => false
                        ],
                        'Banner Name'
                    )
                    ->addColumn(
                        'status',
                        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                        null,
                        [
                            'nullable' => false,
                            'default'    => '1'
                        ],
                        'Banner Status: Enabled is: 1, Disabled is: 2'
                    )
                    ->addColumn(
                        'created_at',
                        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                        null,
                        [
                            'nullable' => false,
                            'default'  => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT,
                        ],
                        'Created At'
                    )
                    ->addColumn(
                        'updated_at',
                        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                        null,
                        [
                            'nullable' => false,
                            'default'  => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE,
                        ],
                        'Updated At'
                    )
                    ->setComment('Slider Table');
                    $installer->getConnection->createTable($table);
                }
            }
            $installer->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

And when I try to run following command:

```
  php bin magento setup:upgrade
```

I am getting following error in command line:

```
  Undefined property: Magento\Setup\Module\Setup::$getConnection in UpgradeSchema.php on line 18
```

I cannot find out what is the problem here. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **`getConnection()`** is function you forgot to mention as function

**Your code should be like this**

```
$table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
$setup->getTable('bt_essence_slider')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: still not working. See my updated code

Comment: what's the error now?

Comment: It is working Mohit. Thanks mate. I forgot to apply same code most below.

Comment: glad i could help.